# How to parse array-of-arrays with Siddhi

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm trying to parse a JSON event stream using WSO2 Streaming Integrator / Siddhi but seem unsuccessful in getting the events properly into the stream.
I'm using dockerimage `wso2/streaming-integrator:1.0.0` to run this on.

I'm sending the following input stream into the SiddhiApp (as an HTTP POST into the Siddhi endpoint):

```
[
    [ 1502942400000, "4261.480" ],
    [ 1503982400000, "1010.312" ]
]
```

My stream definition is as follows:

```
@source(type='http', receiver.url='http://0.0.0.0:5010/stream', @map(type='json', @attributes(
        timestamp = "[0]", sensorvalue = "[1]"
        )))
define stream SensorAlertsStream (
    timestamp long,
    sensorvalue double,
```

I'm using postman to send the data into WSO2 Streaming Integrator but all I get is errors or no response at all.

I have tried the following attributes configuration, all with unsuccessful results:

```
 - timestamp = "$.[0]", sensorvalue = "$.[1]"
 - timestamp = "$[0]", sensorvalue = "$[1]"
 - timestamp = "$[0][0]", sensorvalue = "$[0][1]"
 - timestamp = "[0]", sensorvalue = "[1]"
```

Am I missing something in the source definition or mapping attribute or should I conclude that this array-of-arrays inputstructure is just no parseable using the siddhi-json mapping?

If it helps; this is my simplified app definition:

```
@App:name("SO-SensorApp")

@source(type='http', receiver.url='http://0.0.0.0:5010/stream', @map(type='json', enclosing.element="$[0]", @attributes( timestamp = "[0]", sensorvalue = "[1]" )) )
define stream SensorAlertsStream ( timestamp long, sensorvalue double );

@sink(type='log', @map(type='json')) 
define stream log_values( sensorvalue double );

from SensorAlertsStream select sensorvalue insert into log_values;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this in Siddhi Tooling 5.1.2 with siddhi-map-json-5.0.6, following configs will solve the issue, enclosing.element- '$', timestamp = "[0]", sensorvalue = "[1]"

```
@source(type = 'http', receiver.url = 'http://0.0.0.0:8007/stream', 
    @map(type = 'json', enclosing.element = "$", 
        @attributes( timestamp = "[0]", sensorvalue = "[1]" )) )
@sink(type = 'log') 
define stream SensorAlertsStream1 ( timestamp long, sensorvalue double );
```

Comment: Thanks @Niveathika! This worked for me and learning something new as the source and sink annotation combo is new to me.